# Draggable jquery ui touch preventing focus on input on Chrome

Tags: html, jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-ui-draggable

I can't click on my inputs and I can't select because of the jquery.ui.touch-punch script I'm using to enable jquery UI drag functionality on touch devices.

Here are the libraries I am using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
            })
        });
</script>
```

And down in my body, I have:

```
<div class="block3 ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
<div class="col">
                            <select class="form-select text-uppercase">
                                <option value="" selected>P</option>
                                <option value="">G</option>
                      <option value="">M</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
<div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Code">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Code agent">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
</diV
```

Anyone familiar with this script that may know why Chrome is stopping the select and the focus on inputs? Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for the input by adding some javascript

```
<script>
    $('form').on('touchstart', 'input',function(){
        $(this).focus();
    });
</script>
```

But i don't know how to force the select. Any idea?